# lock not working in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, locking

`Lock` is not working as expected, here is the code.
I am applying thread here, but I will apply it to **ASP.NET** application.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadManager.CurrentSession = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                CreateWork objCreateWork = new CreateWork();
                ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(objCreateWork.ProcessQuickPLan);
                new Thread(start).Start();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class CreateWork
    {
        private object CurrentSession = -1;
        public void ProcessQuickPLan()
        {
            lock (CurrentSession)
            {
                CurrentSession = ThreadManager.CurrentSession;
                Console.WriteLine(CurrentSession);
                ThreadManager.CurrentSession = Convert.ToInt32(ThreadManager.CurrentSession) + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    class ThreadManager
    {
        public static object CurrentSession
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

It is giving me following output

```
0
0
0
3
4
4
6
7
8
9
```

And I am expecting

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Should I use `readonly object` as described here  [C# lock(mylocker) not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143557/c-sharp-lockmylocker-not-work)

Comment: I can't use `readonly` objects, please help to find alternative if `readonly` is the solution

Comment: Why can't you use `readonly` ?? That kind of artificial constraints is always weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that each of your threads has its own lock. Making `CurrentSession` static should fix the problem: there will be only one object to lock on. You should also stop re-assigning it in your code.

```
class CreateWork
{
    private static readonly object LockObject = -1; // Although -1 works here, it's really misleading
    // You should consider replacing the above with a "plain" new object();
    private object CurrentSession = -1; 
    public void ProcessQuickPLan()
    {
        lock (LockObject)
        {
            CurrentSession = ThreadManager.CurrentSession;
            Console.WriteLine(CurrentSession);
            ThreadManager.CurrentSession = Convert.ToInt32(ThreadManager.CurrentSession) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a [working demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/J2Pavs).

Comment: `CurrentSession` is static object

Comment: no it is not helpful, and even `ThreadManager.CurrentSession` is static

Comment: @WouterdeKort It does not matter what object you use - `-1` wrapped as an object will work just fine.

Comment: That's not true, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267323/why-cant-we-lock-on-a-value-type

Comment: @WouterdeKort That question has decidedly nothing to do with what the OP is doing: the fact that he's using a boxed `Int32` does not make `object` ineligible for locking.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `private static object LockObject = -1;` this line is really helpful, and I am close to solve it. Thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate that how lock works or can share some article.

Comment: thanks @dasblinkenlight, I accepted your answer, please share some article on this

Comment: You: _You should also stop re-assigning it_ Correct. Then, to be more sure it is not reassigned, why not use the `readonly` modifier on the field?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That's a great suggestion, I made an edit. Thanks!

Comment: @vikas I don't know a good article that would explain this, but there is only one thing to check when the lock does not lock: "is this the same object?" In your case the answer was "no", because the code has been assigning new objects to the variable on which you lock. It is a good idea to make your lock object readonly. [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) has a couple of important remarks on the subject, but that is all that you need to know in order to apply `lock` successfully.

Comment: thanks JeppeStigNielsen and dasblinkenlight for your great comments. and even for your great answers

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the object you use to lock on. You are using an instance variable so each instance has its own `lock`, that is fundamentally wrong.

The second issue is the initialization with `-1`, that is at least confusing.

The simple solution is a `static object CurrentSession = new object();`

The next issue is `CurrentSession = ThreadManager.CurrentSession;` . This makes no sense and is inherently wrong. I'm surprised it even compiles.

```
class CreateWork
{
    private object CurrentSession = -1;   // boxed int, Id only
    private static object _locker = new object();

    public void ProcessQuickPLan()
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            CurrentSession = ThreadManager.CurrentSession;
            Console.WriteLine(CurrentSession);
            ThreadManager.CurrentSession = Convert.ToInt32(ThreadManager.CurrentSession) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Summary: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. CurrentSession seems to have a double role as lock guard and Id. Not a good plan.

Basically you want 1 private static object to guard a resource. Never assign to it after initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you lock an object in its own thread, so it will never really locked.

Better use global object, which will be locked.

Comment: I didn't get actually, please elaborate

Comment: @vikas You have `private object CurrentSession`. There's no `static` there. That means that each new `CreateWork` instance has its own `CurrentSession` object. So they are locking on different objects. To work, it must be the same instance they lock on. Make the field `static` (or "global").

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, it means object should be static

Answer (score 0):

Each Thread contains its own instance of `CreateWork`with a locker. 
Try this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadManager.CurrentSession = 0;
        CreateWork objCreateWork = new CreateWork();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(objCreateWork.ProcessQuickPLan);
            new Thread(start).Start();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class CreateWork
{
    private object CurrentSession = -1;
    public void ProcessQuickPLan()
    {
        lock (CurrentSession)
        {
            CurrentSession = ThreadManager.CurrentSession;
            Console.WriteLine(CurrentSession);
            ThreadManager.CurrentSession = Convert.ToInt32(ThreadManager.CurrentSession) + 1;
        }
    }
}

class ThreadManager
{
    public static object CurrentSession
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadManager.CurrentSession = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            CreateWork objCreateWork = new CreateWork();
            ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(objCreateWork.ProcessQuickPLan);
            new Thread(start).Start();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class CreateWork
{
    private static object _lock = new Object();

    public void ProcessQuickPLan()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {            
            Console.WriteLine(ThreadManager.CurrentSession);
            ThreadManager.CurrentSession++;
        }
    }
}

class ThreadManager
{
    public static int CurrentSession
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The important thing is the separation between your lock and tracking your id.

The private lock is a static object so that it's shared between the threads. I've also removed assigning a new value to the lock each time.