# Why does the lock object have to be readonly?

Tags: c#, multithreading

When implementing a lock, I used to create a private object inside of my class:

If I want to be sure that it is locked in the thread that created my class:

```
private object Locker = new object();
```

If I want to be sure that it will be locked for all threads inside my application:

```
private static object Locker = new object();
```

But here:
[Why does the lock object have to be static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053172/why-does-the-lock-object-have-to-be-static)

and in a number of other questions, everyone says that the object has to be `readonly`. I haven't found the reason - not even in MSDN or JavaDoc.

As I use this kind of construction quite often, could someone explain to me why should I use `readonly`?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no need for Locker (either static or not) to be readonly; but the code looks more accurate if Locker is readonly: we stress out that Locker instance can't be changed

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> If I want to be sure that it will be locked for all threads inside my
>   application:

The lock object has to be static, if it locks access to static state.
Otherwise it has to be instance, because there's no need to lock state of one class instance, and prevent other threads to work with another class instance at the same time.

> everyone says that the object has to be "readonly" I didn't found the
>   reason

Well, it doesn't *have to* be. This is just a best practice, which helps you to avoid errors.

Consider this code:

```
class MyClass
{
    private object myLock = new object();
    private int state;

    public void Method1()
    {
        lock (myLock)
        {
            state = // ...
        }
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        myLock = new object();
        lock (myLock)
        {
            state = // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here Thread1 can acquire lock via `Method1`, but Thread2, which is going to execute `Method2`, will ignore this lock, because lock object was changed => the state can be corrupted.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for the explanation. Probably because I'm used to create different locks depending on the resource (or method) that I want to access, I never got in this situation, but now I understand that in any case the readonly is a good practice that won't harm my code.

Comment: @Dennis, readonly make sense. But static is not required in lock. suppose i will not mark readonly  if use static only , behaviour will be same as   private object myLock = new object();

Comment: @Sudhir.net: I'm afraid, I didn't understand your point. `static` is required when `myLock` protects *static* state (that is, static fields). If you omit `static` in this case, each type instance will have its own `myLock`, and this makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. myLock vairable is private to any specific class. It will not shared among other classes. If i will use readonly then nobody can create the object. So state will be not changed  then inside one class state of myLock will not be changed. Then my question is what is need of need of Static with myLock ?

Comment: @Sudhir.net: You need `static` if code inside `lock (myLock) { ... }` accesses static fields, because static fields are shared among class *instances*. If code inside `lock`  works only with instance fields (that is, fields, declared without `static` keyword), don't use `static` for `myLock`.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, Got it!

Answer (score 21):

It doesn't have to be readonly, but it's good practice to as it saves you from accidentally replacing it, which can lead to some difficult to track down bugs.

Answer (score 12):

I guess what meant is "a variable referencing a lock object should be read only".

You lock on a lock object that variable references, not on a variable itself. I.e. having

```
private object Locker = new object();
```

you lock on that new object(), not on Locker field. Then, if you replace the value of the field with a reference to another object, say

```
Locker = new object();
```

and lock on it, you are locking on **two different objects**, and that defeats the purpose of the locking, because you do not get a synchronized access now.

Answer (score 7):

The object should ideally be readonly so that it cannot be changed to point to another object.  If you took a lock on an object, then another thread changes the object, if, then another thread comes along, and tries to take a lock on this object, the object in question would not be the same, so the original lock would be invalidated.

This would be a very rare case.  But if you had a lock on the object, and another thread waiting on that object, if the locking thread calls Monitor.Pulse, the waiting thread is awoken, and can take the lock on the object.  In that period of time between being woken and taking the lock, another thread could change the object that is referenced in the lock, and so the waiting thread would take a lock on a different object.