# Lock over a static lock object

Tags: c#, locking

I'm using a static cache on a service and I found a problem of concurrence in NHibernate Session when the key was missing and was forced to get from database (using Evict).

I wrote a lock sentence on the code (an abstraction below) to solve the problem, but i can't understand that the lock was not working. Finally I put readonly on the static "lock" variable and worked, but I can't understand why not working when the assign of the static variable was only on top of the class, how it works?

```
private static object lockCacheElement = new object()

....

public static T ManageCacheElement<T>(int objectId, string key, Func<T> findById) {
    lock (lockCacheElement) 
    {
        Log.DebugFormat("ManageCacheElement({0}): START", key);
        if (TryGetDataElement<T>(key, out result))
        {
            Log.DebugFormat("ManageCacheElement({0}): END1 ", key);
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            result = findById(objectId, true);
            SetDataElement(key, result);
            Log.DebugFormat("ManageCacheElement({0}): END2 ", key);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

That code traces something like that:

```
{DEBUG} 28/11 17:37:01.0423 [67] - ManageCacheElement(xxx): START
{DEBUG} 28/11 17:37:01.0423 [72] - ManageCacheElement(xxx): START
{DEBUG} 28/11 17:37:01.0423 [72] - ManageCacheElement(xxx): END1 
{DEBUG} 28/11 17:37:01.0423 [92] - ManageCacheElement(xxx): START
{DEBUG} 28/11 17:37:01.0423 [92] - ManageCacheElement(xxx): END1 
{DEBUG} 28/11 17:37:01.0580 [96] - ManageCacheElement(xxx): START
{DEBUG} 28/11 17:37:01.0580 [96] - ManageCacheElement(xxx): END1 
{DEBUG} 28/11 17:37:01.0580 [10] - ManageCacheElement(xxx): START
```

And if I set the readonly modifier on lockCacheElement.

```
private static readonly object lockCacheElement = new object()
```

It works fine, but I can't understand why?

Comment: It [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22063191/11683) without `readonly`.

Comment: I think so! I have the theory so clear, but there's something i can't understand...

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write `=>` rather than `=` when you first wrote it?

Comment: Do you refer on lockCacheElement assignation? No.

Comment: Also log [AddrOfPinnedObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.addrofpinnedobject?view=netframework-4.7.2) of `lockCacheElement`. Are they the same?